# Kiosk a raspberry pi

Tags: chromium, kiosk

I know what you're thinking, "this has been asked a thousand times" and you're right, but why is it none of the answers are helpful? I have a brand new pi, I'm using the April 2017 release of NOOBS. I plugged it in and get a Windows looking interface. Unfortunately, every answer has a ton of DIFFERENT code ideas, none of which seem to work.

I want to be able to plug it in, have it launch straight into a full screen browser, with screensaver (blank) disabled. That's it, nothing fancy, no other plans for the device.

I'm comfortable coding... I found the terminal, I believe I've learned how to create, open, edit, etc. My issue is that there are a boatload of answers to making a kiosk out of your pi. I've tried at least a dozen, and none of them work. The best I've gotten is a launch of Chromium as soon as GUI comes up.... before the wifi connects. But... not fullscreen, and the screensaver came on.

There has got to be an easier way... so many people are kiosk'ing their pi's. I've been programming so long I'm convinced I'm missing something incredibly obvious... but after trying so many different solutions and not getting any of them to do ... anything. I'm feeling lost!

Comment: First of all it is Noobs not newbs.

Comment: https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS

Comment: Apologies, was trying to be funny, because I'm feeling way out of my element...

Comment: Funny at the cost of clarity doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Good call - original edited. I'm new to the scene, but appears your answer is to drop NOOBS and switch to what you've linked to instead. Downloading and giving it a go!

Comment: So, if I plug it into my router directly, this works exactly like I had intended, kudos for understanding my needs. My issue is I can't make it connect wirelessly - I even rebuilt router as unsecured... nada.

Comment: How are you configuring the wireless on the Pi? and what model Pi do you have?

Answer (score -1):

Use calmwm (cwm), and in your startup script invoke a program which fills the entire screen (Ex. something written with python's Tkinter). Add your functionality there. Without a keyboard you can't get at calmwm's controls, ex. C-M-? and similar functions. Ensure that your fullscreen app respawns if it dies for whatever reason.

You need a touchscreen, of course. You can use vanilla Xorg, or some other WM, but cwm is 'invisible' by default, and completely customizable.